# Numerical Value of Bools in Solidity

Tags: solidity, evm

What is the numerical value of true and false? Presumably one is 0x0000000000000000 and one is 0x0000000000000001

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no type conversion from non-boolean to boolean types as there is in C and JavaScript, so if (1) { ... } is not valid Solidity. (from the official doc)

but generally a true would be any value !=0;

so you can use :

```
check = isittrue ? 1 : 0;
```